# what's the best way to parse xml response in AJAX

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I have a server that response the request with XML, I want to parse it in the javascript. I really like the actionscript xml parser that is really easy for me to use. I am wandering is there a very easy/straightforward way to parse the XML I fetched from server?

The ideal usage should be:

fetchXML
new XMLParser.
parser.parse
access the document.

btw I plan to use jquery.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A regular `$.ajax` with `dataType: "xml"` will do the trick, then you can browse the contents with jQuery selectors like you would a simple web page (e.g. the `attr` function in the example to retrieve the "code" field of each book node or the `find` function to find specific node types).

For example, you could do this to find a specific book by title:

```
$(xml).find("book[title='Cinderella']")
```

where `xml` is the data the `success` handler receives from `$.ajax`.

---

Here is the complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>jQuery and XML</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="language" content="en" />
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body

<div id="output"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "xml",
  url: "example.xml",
  success: function(xml){
   $(xml).find("book").each(function(){
    $("#output").append($(this).attr("code") + "<br />");
   });
  }
 });
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

And a matching XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<books title="A list of books">
 <book code="abcdef" />
 <book code="ghijklm">
  Some text contents
 </book>
</books>
```

Comment: Thanks! If I don't want to find and the result only contains "<book code="kdjfkjd" /> how I can reference the "book" element?

Comment: $(xml).find("book") gives you a list of the book nodes. In the "each" loop, $(this) is a reference to the book node.

Comment: yes but for my code I don't want the find because it's unnecessary, i only have one book element, is it possible to reference it directly without find?

Comment: If you have only one node, then you can directly use the result of $(xml).find("book"), like $(xml).find("book").attr('code')

Comment: Otherwise, $(xml).children() is an alternative if you don't like the find method

Answer (score 3):

Return the data with the right content type (e.g. `application/xml`) and XHR will parse it for you.

See also: the dataType argument for jQuery's [ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).