# Parsing JSON query (and xml)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

I would need to parse some data that i get from JSON query. I get the data with

```
$.getJSON(JSONquery, function(data){
   $.each(data, function(i,item){
$('#output....
});
```

The data I get from it something like this (sorry its messy and longish):

```
[{"name":"139930 blablabla","id":599,"contentobject_id":599,"main_node_id":565,"modified":"1287146683","published":"1264417592","section_id":1,"current_language":"eng","owner_id":193,"class_id":28,"class_name":"Product","class_identifier":"product","is_container":0,"node_id":565,"parent_node_id":355,"url_alias":"Products\/blablabla\/blablabla\/139930-blablabla","depth":6,"path":false,"children_count":false,"image_attributes":["main_image","listing_thumbnail","promo_badge"],"data_map":{"title":{"id":"6488","type":"ezstring","identifier":"title","content":"blablabla"},"short_title":{"id":"6489","type":"ezstring","identifier":"short_title","content":"139930 blablabla"},"subtitle":{"id":"6490","type":"ezstring","identifier":"subtitle","content":""},"authors":{"id":"6491","type":"ezauthor","identifier":"authors","content":"blablabla blablabla | blablabla@ blablabla .com|0"},"keywords":{"id":"6492","type":"ezkeyword","identifier":"keywords","content":"blablabla"},"item_id":{"id":"6493","type":"ezstring","identifier":"item_id","content":"139930"},"price":{"id":"6494","type":"ezprice","identifier":"price","content":"0|1|1"},"is_shoppable":{"id":"6495","type":"ezboolean","identifier":"is_shoppable","content":"0"},"main_image":{"id":"6496","type":"ezimage","identifier":"main_image","content":{"reference":false,"small":{"name":"small","width":"100","height":"33","mime_type":"image\/jpeg","filename":"139930-blablabla_small.jpg","suffix":"jpg","dirpath":"var\/blablabal_blablabal\/storage\/images\/frontpage\/products\/lawn-blablabla\/blablabla\/139930-blablabla\/6496-25-eng-EU","alias_key":"2343348577","timestamp":"1286700665","is_valid":"1","url":"var\/blablabla\/storage\/images\/frontpage\/products\/blablabla-care\/blablabla\/139930-blablabla/6496-25-eng-EU\/139930-blablabla-blablablar_small.jpg","basename":"139930-blablabla-blablablar","alternative_text":"","text":"","original_filename":"139930_2.jpg","full_path":"var\/blablabal_blablabal\/storage\/images\/frontpage\/products\/blab-bla\/blaaders\/139930-blablabla-blablablar\/6496-25-eng-EU\/139930-blablabla-blablablar_small.jpg","is_new":false,"info":{"Height":"200","Width":"600","IsColor":"1"}},"tiny":false,"medium":false,"large":false,"rss":false,"width100":false,"width150":false,"width200":false,"width300":false,"width400":false,"product_main":false,"product_main_large":false,"product_listing":false,"product_category_listing":false,"product_media_listing":false,"rc_full":false,"main_banner":false,"main_banner_front":false,"promo_badge":false,"multiuploadthumbnail":false,"original":{"url":"var\/blablabal_blablabal\/storage\/images\/frontpage\/products\/blab-bla\/blaaders\/139930-blablabla-blablablar\/6496-25-eng-EU\/139930-blablabla-blablablar.jpg|"}}},"listing_thumbnail":{"id":"6497","type":"ezimage","identifier":"listing_thumbnail","content":{"reference":false,"small":null,"tiny":false,"medium":false,"large":false,"rss":false,"width100":false,"width150":false,"width200":false,"width300":false,"width400":false,"product_main":false,"product_main_large":false,"product_listing":false,"product_category_listing":false,"product_media_listing":false,"rc_full":false,"main_banner":false,"main_banner_front":false,"promo_badge":false,"multiuploadthumbnail":false,"original":{"url":"var\/blablabal_blablabal\/storage\/images\/frontpage\/products\/blab-bla\/blaaders\/139930-blablabla-blablablar\/6497-25-eng-EU\/139930-blablabla-blablablar.jpg|"}}},"related_images":{"id":"6498","type":"ezobjectrelationbrowse","identifier":"related_images","content":"605"},"related_media":{"id":"6499","type":"ezobjectrelationbrowse","identifier":"related_media","content":""},"related_products":{"id":"6500","type":"ezobjectrelationbrowse","identifier":"related_products","content":""},"related_faq_items":{"id":"6501","type":"ezobjectrelationbrowse","identifier":"related_faq_items","content":""},"awards":{"id":"6502","type":"ezxmltext","identifier":"awards","content":"\n
        \n"},"country_awards":{"id":"601924","type":"ezxmltext","identifier":"country_awards","content":"\n


    \n"},"description":{"id":"6503","type":"ezxmltext","identifier":"description","content":"\n
        blablabla<\/line><\/paragraph><\/section>\n"},"features":{"id":"6504","type":"ezxmltext","identifier":"features","content":"\n
         • blablabla <\/paragraph><\/li>
         • blablabla <\/paragraph><\/li>
         • blablabla <\/paragraph><\/li>
         • blablabla <\/paragraph><\/li>
         • C blablabla <\/paragraph><\/li><\/ul><\/paragraph><\/section>\n"},"freeform_1_title":{"id":"6505","type":"ezstring","identifier":"freeform_1_title","content":""},"freeform_1_content":{"id":"6506","type":"ezxmltext","identifier":"freeform_1_content","content":"\n\n"},"freeform_2_title":{"id":"6507","type":"ezstring","identifier":"freeform_2_title","content":""},"freeform_2_content":{"id":"6508","type":"ezxmltext","identifier":"freeform_2_content","content":"\n\n"},"freeform_3_title":{"id":"6509","type":"ezstring","identifier":"freeform_3_title","content":""},"freeform_3_content":{"id":"6510","type":"ezxmltext","identifier":"freeform_3_content","content":"\n\n"},"promo_badge":{"id":"277833","type":"ezimage","identifier":"promo_badge","content":{"reference":false,"small":null,"tiny":false,"medium":false,"large":false,"rss":false,"width100":false,"width150":false,"width200":false,"width300":false,"width400":false,"product_main":false,"product_main_large":false,"product_listing":false,"product_category_listing":false,"product_media_listing":false,"rc_full":false,"main_banner":false,"main_banner_front":false,"promo_badge":false,"multiuploadthumbnail":false,"original":{"url":"|"}}},"weight":{"id":"433850","type":"ezstring","identifier":"weight","content":"1052"},"length":{"id":"433851","type":"ezstring","identifier":"length","content":"970"},"product_attributes":{"id":"691877","type":"blamatrix","identifier":"product_attributes","content":{"HTTPValue":null,"Content":null,"DisplayInfo":null,"IsValid":null,"ContentClassAttributeID":"891","ValidationError":null,"ValidationLog":null,"ContentClassAttributeIdentifier":"product_attributes","ContentClassAttributeCanTranslate":null,"ContentClassAttributeName":null,"ContentClassAttributeIsInformationCollector":null,"ContentClassAttributeIsRequired":null,"PersistentDataDirty":false,"InputParameters":false,"HasValidationError":false,"DataTypeCustom":null,"ID":"691877","ContentObjectID":"599","Version":"26","LanguageCode":"eng-EU","LanguageID":"8","AttributeOriginalID":"0","SortKeyInt":"0","SortKeyString":"","DataTypeString":"blamatrix","DataText":"\n<\/name>Title<\/column>Content<\/column><\/columns>Description<\/c><ul><li>I NEED THIS DESC TEXT<\/li><\/ul><\/c>SOME TITLE<\/c><ul><li>THIS TEXT<\/li><\/ul><\/c>THIS TITLE<\/c>THIS TEXT<\/c>THIS TITLE<\/c>AGAIN THIS TEXT<\/c>THIS TITLE<\/c><ul><li>THIS TEXAT<\/li><\/ul><\/c>THIS TITLE<\/c><ul><li>THIS TEXT<\/li><\/ul><\/c>YEP THIS TITLE<\/c>THIS<\/c><\/blamatrix>\n","DataInt":null,"DataFloat":"0"}}}}]
```

I would need to get those 'THIS TEXT/TITLE' parts and append them inot a table. Here a cut from that huge output (so this part i would need to parse):

```
{
    "id": "691877",
    "type": "blamatrix",
    "identifier": "product_attributes",
    "content": {
        "HTTPValue": null,
        "Content": null,
        "DisplayInfo": null,
        "IsValid": null,
        "ContentClassAttributeID": "891",
        "ValidationError": null,
        "ValidationLog": null,
        "ContentClassAttributeIdentifier": "product_attributes",
        "ContentClassAttributeCanTranslate": null,
        "ContentClassAttributeName": null,
        "ContentClassAttributeIsInformationCollector": null,
        "ContentClassAttributeIsRequired": null,
        "PersistentDataDirty": false,
        "InputParameters": false,
        "HasValidationError": false,
        "DataTypeCustom": null,
        "ID": "691877",
        "ContentObjectID": "599",
        "Version": "26",
        "LanguageCode": "eng-EU",
        "LanguageID": "8",
        "AttributeOriginalID": "0",
        "SortKeyInt": "0",
        "SortKeyString": "",
        "DataTypeString": "blamatrix",
        "DataText": "\n<\/name>Title<\/column>Content<\/column><\/columns>Description<\/c><ul><li>I NEED THIS DESC TEXT<\/li><\/ul><\/c>SOME TITLE<\/c><ul><li>THIS TEXT<\/li><\/ul><\/c>THIS TITLE<\/c>THIS TEXT<\/c>THIS TITLE<\/c>AGAIN THIS TEXT<\/c>THIS TITLE<\/c><ul><li>THIS TEXAT<\/li><\/ul><\/c>THIS TITLE<\/c><ul><li>THIS TEXT<\/li><\/ul><\/c>YEP THIS TITLE<\/c>THIS<\/c><\/blamatrix>\n",
        "DataInt": null,
        "DataFloat": "0" 
    }
}
```

---

Here is the content of that DataText attribute that I would need to parse:

```
<blamatrixrix>
<name></name>
<columns number="2">
    <column id="title" num="0">Title</column>
    <column id="content" num="1">Content</column>
</columns>
<rows number="7"></rows>
<c>Description</c>
<c><ul><li>Description text here</li></ul></c>
<c>Some title</c>
<c>Some text blabla</c>
<c>Some title</c>
<c>Some text blabla</c>
<c>Some title</c>
<c>Some text blabla</c>
<c>Some title</c>
<c>Some text blabla</c>
<c>Some title</c>
<c>Some text blabla</c>
<c>Some title</c>
<c>Some text blabla</c>
</blamatrixrix>
```

So titles to own  and some texts to own . Im still not sure how to parse inside of that :(

Answer (score 0):

some of your data is not valid juston where you have line breaks that might be due to how you copied and pasted but I cleaned it up here is what you need

```
 var data = [{
     "name": "139930 blablabla",
     "id": 599,
     "contentobject_id": 599,
     "main_node_id": 565,
     "modified": "1287146683",
     "published": "1264417592",
     "section_id": 1,
     "current_language": "eng",
     "owner_id": 193,
     "class_id": 28,
     "class_name": "Product",
     "class_identifier": "product",
     "is_container": 0,
     "node_id": 565,
     "parent_node_id": 355,
     "url_alias": "Products\/blablabla\/blablabla\/139930-blablabla",
     "depth": 6,
     "path": false,
     "children_count": false,
     "image_attributes": ["main_image", "listing_thumbnail", "promo_badge"],
     "data_map": {
         "title": {
             "id": "6488",
             "type": "ezstring",
             "identifier": "title",
             "content": "blablabla"
         },
         "short_title": {
             "id": "6489",
             "type": "ezstring",
             "identifier": "short_title",
             "content": "139930 blablabla"
         },
         "subtitle": {
             "id": "6490",
             "type": "ezstring",
             "identifier": "subtitle",
             "content": ""
         },
         "authors": {
             "id": "6491",
             "type": "ezauthor",
             "identifier": "authors",
             "content": "blablabla blablabla | blablabla@ blablabla .com|0"
         },
         "keywords": {
             "id": "6492",
             "type": "ezkeyword",
             "identifier": "keywords",
             "content": "blablabla"
         },
         "item_id": {
             "id": "6493",
             "type": "ezstring",
             "identifier": "item_id",
             "content": "139930"
         },
         "price": {
             "id": "6494",
             "type": "ezprice",
             "identifier": "price",
             "content": "0|1|1"
         },
         "is_shoppable": {
             "id": "6495",
             "type": "ezboolean",
             "identifier": "is_shoppable",
             "content": "0"
         },
         "main_image": {
             "id": "6496",
             "type": "ezimage",
             "identifier": "main_image",
             "content": {
                 "reference": false,
                 "small": {
                     "name": "small",
                     "width": "100",
                     "height": "33",
                     "mime_type": "image\/jpeg",
                     "filename": "139930-blablabla_small.jpg",
                     "suffix": "jpg",
                     "dirpath": "var\/blablabal_blablabal\/storage\/images\/frontpage\/products\/lawn-blablabla\/blablabla\/139930-blablabla\/6496-25-eng-EU",
                     "alias_key": "2343348577",
                     "timestamp": "1286700665",
                     "is_valid": "1",
                     "url": "var\/blablabla\/storage\/images\/frontpage\/products\/blablabla-care\/blablabla\/139930-blablabla/6496-25-eng-EU\/139930-blablabla-blablablar_small.jpg",
                     "basename": "139930-blablabla-blablablar",
                     "alternative_text": "",
                     "text": "",
                     "original_filename": "139930_2.jpg",
                     "full_path": "var\/blablabal_blablabal\/storage\/images\/frontpage\/products\/blab-bla\/blaaders\/139930-blablabla-blablablar\/6496-25-eng-EU\/139930-blablabla-blablablar_small.jpg",
                     "is_new": false,
                     "info": {
                         "Height": "200",
                         "Width": "600",
                         "IsColor": "1"
                     }
                 },
                 "tiny": false,
                 "medium": false,
                 "large": false,
                 "rss": false,
                 "width100": false,
                 "width150": false,
                 "width200": false,
                 "width300": false,
                 "width400": false,
                 "product_main": false,
                 "product_main_large": false,
                 "product_listing": false,
                 "product_category_listing": false,
                 "product_media_listing": false,
                 "rc_full": false,
                 "main_banner": false,
                 "main_banner_front": false,
                 "promo_badge": false,
                 "multiuploadthumbnail": false,
                 "original": {
                     "url": "var\/blablabal_blablabal\/storage\/images\/frontpage\/products\/blab-bla\/blaaders\/139930-blablabla-blablablar\/6496-25-eng-EU\/139930-blablabla-blablablar.jpg|"
                 }
             }
         },
         "listing_thumbnail": {
             "id": "6497",
             "type": "ezimage",
             "identifier": "listing_thumbnail",
             "content": {
                 "reference": false,
                 "small": null,
                 "tiny": false,
                 "medium": false,
                 "large": false,
                 "rss": false,
                 "width100": false,
                 "width150": false,
                 "width200": false,
                 "width300": false,
                 "width400": false,
                 "product_main": false,
                 "product_main_large": false,
                 "product_listing": false,
                 "product_category_listing": false,
                 "product_media_listing": false,
                 "rc_full": false,
                 "main_banner": false,
                 "main_banner_front": false,
                 "promo_badge": false,
                 "multiuploadthumbnail": false,
                 "original": {
                     "url": "var\/blablabal_blablabal\/storage\/images\/frontpage\/products\/blab-bla\/blaaders\/139930-blablabla-blablablar\/6497-25-eng-EU\/139930-blablabla-blablablar.jpg|"
                 }
             }
         },
         "related_images": {
             "id": "6498",
             "type": "ezobjectrelationbrowse",
             "identifier": "related_images",
             "content": "605"
         },
         "related_media": {
             "id": "6499",
             "type": "ezobjectrelationbrowse",
             "identifier": "related_media",
             "content": ""
         },
         "related_products": {
             "id": "6500",
             "type": "ezobjectrelationbrowse",
             "identifier": "related_products",
             "content": ""
         },
         "related_faq_items": {
             "id": "6501",
             "type": "ezobjectrelationbrowse",
             "identifier": "related_faq_items",
             "content": ""
         },
         "awards": {
             "id": "6502",
             "type": "ezxmltext",
             "identifier": "awards",
             "content": "\n\n"
         },
         "country_awards": {
             "id": "601924",
             "type": "ezxmltext",
             "identifier": "country_awards",
             "content": "\n\n"
         },
         "description": {
             "id": "6503",
             "type": "ezxmltext",
             "identifier": "description",
             "content": "\nblablabla<\/line><\/paragraph><\/section>\n"
         },
         "features": {
             "id": "6504",
             "type": "ezxmltext",
             "identifier": "features",
             "content": "\n• blablabla <\/paragraph><\/li>• blablabla <\/paragraph><\/li>• blablabla <\/paragraph><\/li>• blablabla <\/paragraph><\/li>• C blablabla <\/paragraph><\/li><\/ul><\/paragraph><\/section>\n"
         },
         "freeform_1_title": {
             "id": "6505",
             "type": "ezstring",
             "identifier": "freeform_1_title",
             "content": ""
         },
         "freeform_1_content": {
             "id": "6506",
             "type": "ezxmltext",
             "identifier": "freeform_1_content",
             "content": "\n\n"
         },
         "freeform_2_title": {
             "id": "6507",
             "type": "ezstring",
             "identifier": "freeform_2_title",
             "content": ""
         },
         "freeform_2_content": {
             "id": "6508",
             "type": "ezxmltext",
             "identifier": "freeform_2_content",
             "content": "\n\n"
         },
         "freeform_3_title": {
             "id": "6509",
             "type": "ezstring",
             "identifier": "freeform_3_title",
             "content": ""
         },
         "freeform_3_content": {
             "id": "6510",
             "type": "ezxmltext",
             "identifier": "freeform_3_content",
             "content": "\n\n"
         },
         "promo_badge": {
             "id": "277833",
             "type": "ezimage",
             "identifier": "promo_badge",
             "content": {
                 "reference": false,
                 "small": null,
                 "tiny": false,
                 "medium": false,
                 "large": false,
                 "rss": false,
                 "width100": false,
                 "width150": false,
                 "width200": false,
                 "width300": false,
                 "width400": false,
                 "product_main": false,
                 "product_main_large": false,
                 "product_listing": false,
                 "product_category_listing": false,
                 "product_media_listing": false,
                 "rc_full": false,
                 "main_banner": false,
                 "main_banner_front": false,
                 "promo_badge": false,
                 "multiuploadthumbnail": false,
                 "original": {
                     "url": "|"
                 }
             }
         },
         "weight": {
             "id": "433850",
             "type": "ezstring",
             "identifier": "weight",
             "content": "1052"
         },
         "length": {
             "id": "433851",
             "type": "ezstring",
             "identifier": "length",
             "content": "970"
         },
         "product_attributes": {
             "id": "691877",
             "type": "blamatrix",
             "identifier": "product_attributes",
             "content": {
                 "HTTPValue": null,
                 "Content": null,
                 "DisplayInfo": null,
                 "IsValid": null,
                 "ContentClassAttributeID": "891",
                 "ValidationError": null,
                 "ValidationLog": null,
                 "ContentClassAttributeIdentifier": "product_attributes",
                 "ContentClassAttributeCanTranslate": null,
                 "ContentClassAttributeName": null,
                 "ContentClassAttributeIsInformationCollector": null,
                 "ContentClassAttributeIsRequired": null,
                 "PersistentDataDirty": false,
                 "InputParameters": false,
                 "HasValidationError": false,
                 "DataTypeCustom": null,
                 "ID": "691877",
                 "ContentObjectID": "599",
                 "Version": "26",
                 "LanguageCode": "eng-EU",
                 "LanguageID": "8",
                 "AttributeOriginalID": "0",
                 "SortKeyInt": "0",
                 "SortKeyString": "",
                 "DataTypeString": "blamatrix",
                 "DataText": "\n<\/name>Title<\/column>Content<\/column><\/columns>Description<\/c><ul><li>I NEED THIS DESC TEXT<\/li><\/ul><\/c>SOME TITLE<\/c><ul><li>THIS TEXT<\/li><\/ul><\/c>THIS TITLE<\/c>THIS TEXT<\/c>THIS TITLE<\/c>AGAIN THIS TEXT<\/c>THIS TITLE<\/c><ul><li>THIS TEXAT<\/li><\/ul><\/c>THIS TITLE<\/c><ul><li>THIS TEXT<\/li><\/ul><\/c>YEP THIS TITLE<\/c>THIS<\/c><\/blamatrix>\n",
                 "DataInt": null,
                 "DataFloat": "0"
             }
         }
     }
 }];
```

above is the variable I made as data since we know you have no problem getting the data and bellow is how you access what you need and put it in to a td of tr of table

```
 $('#td_id').append(data[0].data_map.product_attributes.content.DataText);
```

Comment: Ah thanks, but I wasnt clear I see. I it possible to get that DataText data in to own td tables? Like this: <td>Descrption</td><td><ul><li>I NEED THIS DESC TEXT<\/li></li> and so on. So that 'SOME TITLE's are in own td cell and 'THIS TEXT's in own td's.

Comment: so what your saying is you want to extract the values of the markup  contained within DataText property and build it into a table?

Comment: I'm not sure... I don't know what mark up that is other than bad since it starts with a closing tag. if it was straight up html and it was good html then I would say there was a good chance

Comment: Well, how shoul I do it then? I could try on that, maybe it works?

Comment: its hard to say be because I image the markup is different on almost every product. So lets assume for a minute that it is the same and its bad you could try using a regex but you might end up with two problems then

Comment: I think the content is (or should be) XML. So i need to parse that xml to get it to table like I said before.

Comment: well then you have your answer all you have to do is parse it like xml and use the results to build the table

Comment: But the thing is, i have no clue how to parse it. Any examples? Do I need to modify the query somehow or something? I am clueless.

Comment: I would just look on this site for jquery xml parsing here is one post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957932/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-xml-response-in-ajax

Comment: So I need to do a seperate XML GET? Or just put the find(something) straight into that code what I have alrady (first post)?