# How to load PHP file that contains XML content and I need to parse the content using phone gap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a php file that it outputs XML content 
Ex: When I run mywebsite.com/generatexmlfile.php. It generates XML content in php file.
THe o/p is as follow when I run:

```
<form><table><CommentsUIDefinition><field><name>email</name><type>textfiled</type></field<field><name>comment</name><type>textarea</type></field><field><name>submit</name><type>button</type></field></CommentsUIDefinition></table>
</form>
```

I do need to call this php file using query or any other method and need to parse this XML content that exist in "generatexmlfile.php". Any references or small help will be great fully help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle which has code to parse raw xml into json which can be used easily.

http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/ShWqt/

For more detail check this post - [what's the best way to parse xml response in AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957932/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-xml-response-in-ajax)