# how to parse xml response from API using jquery,ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

When i request a server i got the following xml response.Can anyone please help me how can i parse this data using jquery.And i want only selected nodes data to parse(student_name,batch_name,admission_date).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<student_detail>
    <student>
        <student_name>sunil </student_name>
        <batch_name>abc</batch_name>
        <admission_date>56-2000</admission_date>
        <blood_group></blood_group>
        <gender>M</gender>
        <nationality>India (भारत)</nationality>
         <city></city>
        <state></state>
        <country>India (भारत)</country>
/student_additional_details>
    </student>
</student_detail>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what's the best way to parse xml response in AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957932/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-xml-response-in-ajax)

Comment: This xml response will vary each time.Then how can i add this response in one xml file to parse.I can save this data in one object.Is any other way to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `parseXML` you can read your value.

```js
var xml = "<student_detail><student><student_name>sunil </student_name><batch_name>abc</batch_name><admission_date>56-2000</admission_date><blood_group></blood_group><gender>M</gender><nationality>India (भारत)</nationality><city></city><state></state><country>India (भारत)</country>/student_additional_details></student></student_detail>";
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
  $xml = $(xmlDoc),
  $student_name = $xml.find("student_name");
$("#someElement").append($student_name.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="someElement"></span>
```

Comment: This is my response code.I cant save the xml data directly.Is any other way to parse the xml data .                                                               function show_response(str){
   str = vkbeautify.xml(str,4);
   return str.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/\n/g,"<br />");
      
              
        }

Comment: this works great as in your example, but when I try to referenceto my code it says invalid XML? What am I missing?

Comment: Hold your response on any variable remove header version part and try .

Comment: I have taken my response in a variable. Which header version u r talking about.I dint get.Could u plz tell that

Comment: still its invalid request

Comment: function show_response(str){
   str = vkbeautify.xml(str,4);
   var xml= str.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/\n/g,"<br />");
 final(xml);
       }

Comment: this is  not a xml.

Comment: I have saved the response in xmlDoc Variable                                          if (xmlhttp .readyState===4)
                        {
                                  xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                         
                               
                        }

Comment: Thank you for your help.I got the data

Comment: If its help accept and up vote answer. Happy Coding :)